# Get DSL even if out of range?

Tags: dsl

So, I currently have dial-up and would like to get DSL, but they say that we're out of range.

I've read where someone asked to be signed up anyway even though he was out of range and bought a DSL modem and it worked. The explanation being that, since DSL works through phone lines, they can still send it to you, but it gets weaker over distance and they might not be able to offer the speed that they say they can. Is this true? Should I try to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, it depends on how far away you are from their distribution point. If you are a mile away, it might work (a friend of mine did what you are asking, and so far it works out ok), but if you are 10 miles away, you are  out of luck.

Maybe you can get wireless or cable internet?

(You could also 'beam' the signal via 802.11 from somewhere else, but that would likely be against the DSL terms of service, and possibly illegal)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm not sure how far away we are, but we're close. They send us flyers asking us to get them, but then when we try to sign up, they say that we're too far away. There aren't many other option though, so I'll try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Satellite Internet access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_Internet_access)

Satellite Internet services are used in locations where terrestrial Internet access is not available, and also for users who move frequently.

Comment: Yeah, but I couldn't deal with the lag with satellite.

Comment: And it's not a relevant answer.